# Get timestamp field from snapshot as Timestamp inside Cloud Function Triggers

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In typescript, I can create document with field like createdAt, updatedAt as Timestamp by using `change.after.updateTime` or `snap.createTime` inside Cloud Functions Triggers.

But inside other triggers like `onUpdate`, the field `change.after.data().updatedAt` that suppose to store a Timestamp, gives me an object.

How can i compare them if i can't get them as Timestamp value ? How can i get the field as Timestamp value ? Thanks

```
admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);


export const setCreatedAt = functions.firestore.document('path')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        return snap.ref.update({
            createdAt: snap.createTime, // Type Timestamp
            updatedAt: snap.createTime // Type Timestamp
        });

    });

export const setUpdatedAt = functions.firestore.document('path')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

        let beforeTimestamp = change.before.data().updatedAt; // Type object, not Timestamp
        let afterTimestamp = change.after.data().updatedAt; // Type object, not Timestamp

        console.log('beforeTimestamp', beforeTimestamp);
        console.log('afterTimestamp', afterTimestamp);

        if (change.before.data().updatedAt === change.after.data().updatedAt) {
            change.after.ref.update({
                updatedAt: change.after.updateTime, // Type Timestamp
            });
        }
    });
```

The image below shows the logs when doing an update.
[image: Example]

It looks like the `{ timestampsInSnapshots: true }` settings has no effect because i still have the warning inside the console. But why ?

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK

Comment: Note that after v0.20.0, the googleapis/nodejs-firestore `timestampsInSnapshots` setting defaults to `true`. So you don't need to explicitly set this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the returned Timestamp objects to Date objects:

```
beforeTimestamp.toDate()
```

Then you can compare the Date objects with `< and >` operators. If you need to compare for equality, then you'll need to convert the dates to numbers first: `beforeTimestamp.toDate().getTime()`

Comment: This is exactly my problem, .toDate is not a function because the variable is of `Type object, not Timestamp`

Comment: You need to be aware that change.before and change.after are both optional properties (they may be undefined). That's also the case for the createTime property.

Comment: Here they're not undefined, when i use typeof change.before.data().updatedAt, it returns `object`. And it should be Timestamp...

Comment: Yes, because as far as javascript is concerned, it's just `object`. Try this: `class Foo {}; a = new Foo(); typeof(a);` It will return `object`.

Comment: Yes i think i agree with you. But it must be of type Timestamp to have the .toDate() function ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp. I think the problem is that timestampsInSnapshot doesn't work here. (For example in my code `snap.createTime` is of type Timestamp.)

Comment: Well you can make the TypeScript compiler ignore the optionality of the parameters by using the _non-null assertion operator_ like this: `const beforeTimestamp = change.before!.data()!.updatedAt;`

Comment: I have the same issue. My date property from the snapshot is of type object. I'm not sure how to get the date out of there.